# Difference between EdgeInsetsGeometry Class EdgeInsets Class in Flutter Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to understand some basic elements of Flutter. When I try to use the property of a container, like padding, I believe that it expects an "EdgeInsetGeometry" class. When I read the document about this class, I see that there is "EdgeInset" class as an implementer. I'm confused about this point since I don't know which one I should use.

The document for Flutter is kind of confusing for me at the moment. Could you please help to explain the difference between these two, and how I can figure out what the type of the output is for a class using flutter document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EdgeInsetsGeometry class** is a class for EdgeInsets that allows for text-direction aware resolution.

**EdgeInsets class** is an immutable set of offsets in each of the four cardinal directions.

Check the article below for more explanation It really helps:

[EdgeInsets and EdgeInsets Geometry](https://medium.com/flutteropen/flutter-widgets-01-container-cc76a2bfef11)

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the article, T.T Sage. So I have a sort of like virtual understanding of it works, I'm just wondering like what type that a class is going to return. Let's say for padding property, it expects an EdgeInsetsGeometry type. So I wonder how I can figure what the type of the output is because I'm not sure where to find it in the flutter document

Comment: Use the ```EdgeInsets``` class to give a widget a padding @DatNguyen

Comment: Do EdgeInsets and EdgeInsetsGeometry both return the object with the type of EdgeInsetsGeometry so that I can match with the expected type of padding? I'm just trying to understand about this

Comment: ```EgdeInsetsGeometry ``` is an abstract class. You can create an instance of it. ```EgdeInsets```(you can create an instance) extends ```EdgeInsetsGeometry``` . Why the ```padding``` property takes ```EdgeInsets``` instead if ```EdgeInsetsGeometry``` @DatNguyen

Comment: Thanks. So when can we use the base class and when can we use the extension class?

Comment: Base class provide some methods or properties to other classes that extends it. So no need to use the base class when you can use the extended class @DatNguyen

Comment: Great, I'm starting to get the hang out of this. So it is safe to assume that Implementers in the Flutter Document shows all the available extended base class, right?

Comment: Let's continue the chat in room. Can you do that @DatNguyen